# Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to make this [captcha](http://www.webdesignbeach.com/beachbar/ajax-fancy-captcha-jquery-plugin) jquery plugin to work. The a certain line of code is executed, the error pops up.

This is the line of code that causes the error :

```
$(".ajax-fc-" + rand).draggable({ containment: '#ajax-fc-content' });
```

What I am assuming is that there is some kind of conflict with the javascript reference, but can't determain what.

These are the referenes that I am using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui.droppable.js"></script>
<script src="js/effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="js/effects.slide.js"></script>
```

Comment: How is your `rand` value defined?

Comment: Hmm it is an ajax request, but apparently it is returning the wrong value. Post an answer and I'll mark it answered for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per RaYell's indirect suggestion the problem was i was returning the wrong value in the ajax response.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem and it was driving me nuts.  Make sure you are passing in the correct objects types to their functions.  I accidentally passed in an structure when it was expecting a string.

This would error:

```
var COUNTRY_CODE = $(aform.COUNTRY_CODE);
$.post("/cfcs/reports/reports.cfc?method=getRegions",
            {COUNTRY_CODE:COUNTRY_CODE}, function(resp) { ...
```

The solution is to add `.val()`, as shown below:

```
var COUNTRY_CODE = $(aform.COUNTRY_CODE);
$.post("/cfcs/reports/reports.cfc?method=getRegions",
           {COUNTRY_CODE:COUNTRY_CODE.val()}, function(resp) { ...
                                     ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work: "jQuery Firefox error: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMViewCSS.getComputedStyle]"

https://siderite.dev/blog/jquery-firefox-error-could-not-convert.html

Answer (score 1):

Add Dojo to the list. I'm Having the same problem with the Dojo Toolkit framework. (Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100915 Ubuntu/9.10 (karmic) Firefox/3.6.10 GTB7.1)

Chrome and Opera work with my code just fine, yet my new update to Linux FireFox gave the same error --> nsresult: ”0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS). I to am doing some positioning of hidden elements as one of the links above describes.

Answer (score 1):

Ooops. My bad. I found the problem. Apparently my new install of FF was picker about a mis-assigned object function. Chrome, Opera and previous FF had no problem with the the essentially "null" function, while the new version did. They just ignored it, so I never knew is wasn't right in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Just place the Draggable Jquery Reference before Core Jquery reference

Answer (score 0):

I am using this method to make jQuery work with jQuery and prototype + scriptaculous: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/