# jQuery-UI dialog $.ajax POST fails due to jQuery "Could not convert JavaScript argument"

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, post, dialog

I'm using the jQuery-UI dialog and I'm trying to send the data in my dialog form via AJAX upon clicking the dialog's send button. Both the `$('').submit()`, `$('').load(url)` methods "work" for me in that the dialog form submits/the url is loaded. However, as i try to add some post data to the load method, like some form input, I get the error message in the firebug console stating that the jQuery library "Could not convert JavaScript argument".

Here's my code that doesn't work yet:

```
$(function(){
  $( "#form" ).dialog({
    buttons: {
      "Send": function() {
        var url = "/messages/add";                          
        var message=$('#message').val();                

        $('#main_content').load(url, { message:message } );     
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }             
    }
  });

  $( "#open_dialog_button" ).click(function() {
    $( "#form" ).dialog( "open" );                  
  }); 
});
```

The problem seems to me to be with the "message" since the "url" will load into the "main_content" Div if I don't include the {message:message} parameter.

Any advice someone might have to help submit this post data I would greatly appreciate,

Comment: Does the element #message have a "value" attribute, and is it available at document ready? Also, it looks like your click-binding function is binding to the button created by the dialog options with a function already bound to it?

Comment: try search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326896/could-not-convert-javascript-argument-arg-0-nsresult-0x80570009-ns-error-xpc

Comment: hi Greg, yes the #message input has a value attribute and I edited my question to make it more clear that the dialog(open) was bound to a unique button. Still getting the error message, but thank you for your comments! -tim

Comment: I think you need $('#main_content').load(url, { "message":message } );

Comment: hi lihoeye, i saw the link you provided but am having trouble adapting what was said there to my situation, can you provide some guidance? thank you, -tim

Comment: hi Dave, i just tried what you said, putting the message key in parentheses, unfortunately that didn't work,  any other suggestions? thanks for your help, -tim

Comment: hi all, I solved the problem, i had misidentified one of my other key:value pairs i didn't mention, now it works! thanks for all your help, -tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, i had misidentified one of my other key:value pairs I didn't mention (besides {message:message}), now it works!