# AJAX NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument jquery.js:7065

Tags: php, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and Ajax and I have run into a problem. Im getting the error on my console that:

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument @ http://localhost
/jquery.js:7065
```

Why am I receiving this error?

this is the code Im Using:

```
function upload_file(){
    var file = document.form1.file_upload;
    var date = document.form1.date_added;
    var author = document.form1.author;
    var user = document.form1.user;
    var semester = document.form1.semester;
    var class1 = document.form1.class;
    var subject = document.form1.subject;
    $.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:"upload_file.php",
        data:{
        "file":file,
        "date":date,
        "author":author,
        "user":user,
        "semester":semester,
        "class":class1,
        "subject":subject
        },
        success:function(result){
        $("#result").html(result);
        }
    });
    }
```

Im waiting for your replies.

> PS: I Did search the forum but did not get what i want, so if i missed something, sorry in advance.

Comment: first of all `class` is a reserved word..change this line var class1 = document.form1.class

Comment: first of all what you trying to do is wrong... you can't upload file using ajax.... if you want ajax like file upload then you have to use iframe.

Comment: second of all why you trying to pass dom object elements to the server... you suppose to pass their values...

Comment: how will i pass their values?

Comment: @ubercooluk please see again... var is class1...

Comment: there are many ajax file uploaders on net... but the dont suit my need...

Answer (score 8):

I think the problem is you are trying to pass complete objects to the JSON.
You should use values instead of objects. For example, replace:

```
var subject = document.form1.subject;
```

with:

```
var subject = document.form1.subject.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this , i guess bracket mismatch --

```
    $.ajax(
                 {
        type:"get",
        url:"upload_file.php",
        data:{
        "file":file,
        "date":date,
        "author":author,
        "user":user,
        "semester":semester,
        "class":class1,
        "subject":subject
        },
        success:function(result)
               {
        $("#result").html(result);
        }
    );
```

Comment: @ZackValentine change class in your form as class is a reserved keyword to something like this myclass and then use it like --  var class1 = document.form1.myclass;

Answer (score 0):

We had the same error.

Upgraded to the latest version of JQuery and problem solved.

[This one seems to work for some people](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2009/07/jquery-firexof-error-could-not-convert.html) seen that solution [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326896/could-not-convert-javascript-argument-arg-0-nsresult-0x80570009-ns-error-xpc)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error, but my problem was different.

Turns out, I was passing a parameter in the ajax call that wasn't present in my DOM at all.

In @ZackValentine-s case (or for someone reading this in the future), please check the value of all the data items you are about to pass to the ajax call, **BEFORE** the actual call itself.